# Need to insert a string that may have double quotes

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a query as follows:

```
$this->db->query('INSERT INTO board_member (name, position, address) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', array($name, $position, $address));
```

The name may contain double quotes, for a nickname, such as:

> James "Jimbo" Smith

However, if I insert that value, It gets cut off before the first double quote, leaving me with just James. What do I need to do to make this work?

EDIT: I've tried $this->db->escape_string(), which left me with this:

> 'James \

Comment: I dont think that this is the problem with the INSERT syntax as you are using Prepared statements. Problem could be something else. Before insertin the value, try to print the `$name` & look what you are getting

Comment: Using var_dump() I get: string(19) "James "Jimbo" Smith"

Comment: i think you could use concatenation in your array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always enclose HTML tag attributes in quotes.
Always use htmlspechialchars() when using a PHP variable in HTML tag attribute.

Comment: You're right - this turned out to be an HTML parsing issue and not a database query issue.

Answer (score -2):

Use `mysql_real_escape_string`

mysql_real_escape_string — Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement

Example

```
`$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);

 $position = file_get_contents($_FILE['file']['tmp_name']);

 $address=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address]);

 $this->db->query('INSERT INTO board_member (name, position, address) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', array($name, $position, $address));`
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)